# Can an iOS app open a BSD network socket in the background?

Tags: ios, sockets, network-programming, background-process

Certain kinds of iOS apps are allowed to periodically run in the background.  For a background-audio, bluetooth-central, or location-fencing app (as listed in the app's capabilities plist), can the iOS app open a BSD network socket (assuming the device has appropriate network connectivity) when given time in the background?

If so, what kind of problems might one encounter when doing this (errors, timeouts, etc.) other than those that an app would see when networking in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

I believe other than the services you mentioned the only other background task you are allowed is via the `NSURLSession` class. Using the `NSUrlSession` class you are allowed to make HTTP requests to a web server while the application is in the background.

For example, you're app could monitor for significant location changes in the background, and during the location change event you could send the GPS coordinates to the web sever via an NSURLSession.

However, from what I understand this is the ONLY networking you're allowed todo while the application is in the background without hacks. Therefore, I do not believe it is possible to open a BSD socket connection while you're app is in the background.